# CSV wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error with CSV in (Rails3, ruby 1.9.2p0, ubuntu)

> error in generate - wrong number of arguements(0 for 1)

Please, can you help me with the soluton for this?

I have used it in this code:

```
csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [
  "S_No",
  "User ID",
  "Password"
  ]

  @password_array.each do |password|
    csv << [
    @user_name,
    @user_id,
    @password]
  end

end
```

I am then sending it in an email as an attachment:

```
UserMailer.export_csv(file_name,csv_data).deliver
```

Comment: Post the code causing the error and explain what are you trying to accomplish. It is impossible to answer this question in its current form.

Comment: csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
      
      csv << [
      "S_No",
      "User ID",
      "Password"
      ]
    
    @password_array.each do |password|
      
      csv << [
      @user_name,
      @user_id,
      @password]

    end
    
  end

Comment: and iam sending this csv_data in mail as attachment

Comment: UserMailer.export_csv(file_name,csv_data).deliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass options to `CSV.generate`.  If you don't care about any options, pass an emtpy hash:

`CSV.generate({}) { |csv| ... }`

Comment: The empty hash is unnecessary. [It's the default](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html#M000182).

Comment: after passing empty hash i still get the error  TypeError (cant convert Hash into String)

Comment: @lamrin: I've been playing around with this, it looks like you may actually be running your script with ruby1.8 instead of ruby1.9 (I get the behavior you describe when running in ruby1.8).  @steenslag is correct that you shouldn't need to pass the empty hash (even in 1.9).

Comment: They don't pass anything in their docs (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exact same problem on Fedora15 with (ruby 1.8.7).
Code below fixed the CSV.generate problem.

```
if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"
require "rubygems"
require "faster_csv"
CSV = FCSV
else
require "csv"
end
```